# VBS Script for replacing commas in excel file then saving file in csv format

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I need to replace commas in a large number of excel workbooks and then save them as csv, I have the following code but don't know why it isn't working:

```
csv_format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook

Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

Dim oBookRange
Set oBookRange = oBook.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

oBookRange.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ReplaceFormat:=False

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

These lines are where it seems to fail:

```
set oBookRange = oBook.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

oBookRange.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: OBookRange is a worksheet and not a Range object.  So it thinks you are tying to replace the worksheet with a different worksheet.  You need to reference the Range of active cells in the worksheet rather than the worksheet itself.

Comment: What is the purpose of replacing the commas?  When Excel saves a .csv file, it adds text qualifiers to cells with a delimiter in them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I need to remove them as the files are bulk inserted into SQL and text qualifiers are causing errors in the bulk insert. I don't think I can use a format file as not all cells have commas just maybe 300 out of 500,000 lines for each file. David are you able to tell me how I would write that? I'm not quite sure as each file will have a different number of cells. Thanks,

Comment: What SQL import system are you using that doesn't recognize text qualifiers on csv input? I'm still thinking that solving *that issue* be a more robust solution than hacking up your input data.  I've found that using Excel as a csv re-formatter usually causes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
Set oBookRange = oBook.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

with:

```
Set oBookRange = oBook.Sheets(1).Cells
```

*There may be other problems.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I have tried this but unfortunately its still not working, it seems to break down here:Replace What:=",", Replacement:=" ",

Comment: @user6823354 SO is about *specific* programming issues. As this answer states, *there may be other problems* - if you're looking for help getting your entire script to work, then your question is too vague to be answered, SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: hi, the entire script works bar these 3 lines                                                                                                                        
Dim oBookRange
Set oBookRange = oBook.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

oBookRange.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ReplaceFormat:=False
 as a last resort i posted on here to see if anyone could provide me with any insight. Thanks.